ServiceBusOutput write to the queue immediately, not on return
I have multiple Azure service bus queues to write to. I must use output bindings. But this output binding cannot be returned to the function endpoints because of the way that the code is structured.
I have this class:
public class OutputBindings
{
    [ServiceBusOutput("%Queue1%", Connection = "ConnnectionString1")]
    public string Queue1 { get; set; }
    
    
    [ServiceBusOutput("%Queue2%", Connection = "ConnnectionString2")]
    public string Queue2 { get; set; }
}

that is in this Function App endpoint:
    [Function("FunctionName")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TriggerQueue%", Connection = "ConnectionString")] string message)
    {
        OutputBindings ob = new OutputBindings()
        {
            Queue1 = message,
            Queue2 = message
        };
        // do other stuff    
    {

This is a really dumbed down pseudocode of this. I cannot return the OutputBindings class. I need the messages to propagate to the two other queues the moment that they are set. Thanks.

What is the constraint of not being able to return the class? The Run as shown doesn't return anything and changing its return type to Task<OutputBindings> should not impact anything else.

Maybe try the same approach as in your other recent Service Bus question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78822781/2325216 - so using ServiceBusClient directly, for two queues; instead of using output buildings. I can write an answer if you can provide a bit more details?

Yeah that would be helpful @AndrewB
The thing is that we need the ServiceBusClient to already be connected when we send the message. We cannot afford the time to connect.

@amit_g I dumbed down the code down for readability reasons. In the old code, we are passing multiple IAsyncCollector to the manager and the manager is calling AddAsync to it. We cannot directly return it without major code refactoring.

Why do you not just inject the queue storage client via dependency injection and call the send method your self if you need more control over it?

@GabrielWhitehair You will achieve this easily if you wish to return OutputBindings

@GabrielWhitehair Use of IAsyncCollector is limited to in-process function only.

Requirements
It sounds like you're wanting to send messages to two different Service Bus queues, ideally simultaneously. Or rather accurately, with the minimum possible delay.
Approach
Here's one approach based on using ServiceBusClient directly, injected by dependency injection. It's similar to the post I referred to in comments, but implementing it directly in the Function class you posted above rather than using a Service.
There are some caveats which I'll list at the end.

// Note the ServiceBusClient is injected from DI config.
public class YourFunctionClass(ServiceBusClient _sbClient)
{
    [Function("FunctionName")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TriggerQueue%", Connection = "ConnectionString")] string message)
    {
        // Get each queue. Note these operations aren't long-running
        // so there's no delay here.
        var queue1 = _client.CreateSender("Queue1Name");
        var queue2 = _client.CreateSender("Queue2Name");

        // Create message content however you wish.
        var message1 = new ServiceBusMessage(Queue1(message));
        var message2 = new ServiceBusMessage(Queue2(message));

        // Create async tasks for each enqueue operation.
        // NB we aren't awaiting the tasks here, so
        // there will be almost no delay executing these lines of code.
        Task task1 = queue1.SendMessageAsync(message);
        Task task2 = queue2.SendMessageAsync(message);

        // Now both those enqueue operations are sent at the same time,
        // and we wait until they're both completed.
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    }

    private string Queue1(string message) => message + "foo"; // your own logic
    private string Queue2(string message) => message + "bar"; //
}


Note the key points:

Inject ServiceBusClient using DI rather than using the Azure Functions output bindings.
Awaiting both Tasks at the same time means that they enqueue at the same time (as much as possible) rather than waiting for the first enqueue before the second one.

Dependency Injection
And some relevant config in Program.cs, for example:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // Register the ServiceBusClient with DI.
        services.AddAzureClients(configureClients =>
        {
            configureClients.AddServiceBusClient("DummyConnectionString");
        });

        // add your other services here too.
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Important caveats

You can't have a queue "already connected" as such. On the plus side, the CreateSender call doesn't take any time at all, so you don't have to worry about connection time. On the down side, that's because you always have a delay when you do that actual enqueuing in SendMessageAsync - ServiceBus is a cloud service, after all.

There's no such thing as "simultaneously" in a cloud context if you have two separate queues. You're firing the requests off at the same time, but there's no guarantee they will both be processed at the exact same time. Cloud is not deterministic in that way.

This is ignoring problems such as one queue succeeding but another one failing to enqueue. Or even that Queue2 trigger its processor before Queue1 has enqueued. You would really need some logic that handles such a situation. It'll need some try/catch and accompanying logic here, and maybe also some logic in the queue processors. Probably you need to give us more detail about what the queue processors are doing at the other end.


Final thoughts
It might be worth you explaining what the two queues are needed for, because perhaps there's a different architecture that would suit the problem. Perhaps avoiding the problem I described above, where one enqueue fails but another succeeds.
Hope that helps!
